# Checking relations in a group

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that we have some group $A$, and another group $C$. Assume they have the same number of elements in their minimal generating sets. Does showing that all the relations satisfied in $C$ are satisfied in $A$ mean that $A$ is a quotient of $C$?

The reason I want to know is that I am working on some hw for an online class, and if this is true I think I have a way to solve the problem.

Comment: You may want, perhaps, to bound somehow the number of generators, as **any** group is generated by all its elements...Perhaps some kind of *minimal set of generators* or something like that?

Comment: @DonAntonio thank you for the feedback! That is indeed what I meant.

Comment: @DonAntonio Minimality is stronger than is needed. You just need generating sets of the same cardinality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is true.

> Form the free group $F$ on the set $X$ of generators, then $C\cong F/N$ where $N$ is the normal subgroup generated by the given relations. Then a homomorphism $\varphi:F\to A$ (which correspond to arbitrary functions $X\to A$) factors through $C$ iff $\ker\varphi \supseteq N$ iff each given relation is satisfied in $A$. The resulting homomorphism will be surjective.

Comment: how do you know that $N$ is normal?

Comment: I defined it as the normal subgroup generated by the given relations: i.e. the intersection of all such normal subgroups.